# Как число int 1-9 перевести в значение 01-09 не преобразовывая в char?

Tags: java, преобразование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как тут сделать, что бы выдаваемое значение было 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12 без преобразование в char? Или только так?

```
    void setMonthMassive(int sizeMax) {
        if (sizeMax <= 12){sizeMax = 12;}
        data_month = new int[sizeMax];
        for(int i = 0; i < data_month.length; i++){
        data_month[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

Вывод находится в другом классе:

```
    int randomV = (int)(Math.random()*data_month.length);
    out_id = data_month[randomV];
    System.out.print(out_id + ".");
```

Comment: где у вас в коде выдыется значение?

Comment: Добавил код с выводом.

Comment: `String.format("%02d",out_id)`

Comment: Спасибо! @Serdov